# how to remove and toggle more/less link when printing excerpt text in a document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I created excerpt text with javascript, where we have "more" link with contracted text first.

Upon clicking more, it will toggle and show entire text and show "less" link.

But, when i try to print the page, i am getting more/less links inside the doc.

How to avoid it ?

Here is my code :

```
<SCRIPT>
$(document).ready(function() {
var showChar = 60;
var ellipsestext = "...";
var moretext = "more";
var lesstext = "less";
$('.more').each(function() {
    var content = $(this).html();

    if(content.length > showChar) {

        var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
        var h = content.substr(showChar-1, content.length - showChar);

        var html = c + '<span class="moreelipses">'+ellipsestext+'</span>&nbsp;<span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">'+moretext+'</a></span>';

        $(this).html(html);
    }

});

$(".morelink").click(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
    } else {
        $(this).addClass("less");
        $(this).html(lesstext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    return false;
});
});
</SCRIPT>
```

I tried this for print button click

```
function myprint() 
{
    //Get the print button and put it into a variable
    var printButton = document.getElementById("printpagebutton");
    //Set the print button visibility to 'hidden' 
    printButton.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    // This is the part where i need to change to toggle text, but not working
    $(".morelink").load(function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
        $(this).removeClass("less");
        $(this).html(moretext);
    }
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();
    });

    //Print the page content
    window.parent.frames[0].focus();
    window.print();
    //Set the print button to 'visible' again 
    //[Delete this line if you want it to stay hidden after printing]
    printButton.style.visibility = 'visible';

}
```

Solution: Put the below code in myPrint() function, instead of what i used previously

```
$(".morelink").each(function(){
    $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
    $(this).prev().toggle();    
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using this

```
    @media print
    {
           .morelink {display:none;}
    }
```

The above css will be applied only if you print the page and not on screen.
Also try to adjust the css of the text div as 100% with media as print.

See these links

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_mediatypes.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_media.asp

Comment: thanks for that SSS, that's useful, the more/less link is disappearing, but the content is not showing fully. I added extra code where i am trying to show entire text. Could you please check that and help me to get entire text while printing.

Comment: It's ok thanks for your help. I achieved it what i want.

Comment: @Java-DK Can you please mark my answer as the right one. So that the question will go out of the Unanswered queue from stack overflow